# How can I send an ImageView to the back?

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` in my Android application. Currently it's in front of the view. I want to send it to the back. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `ImageView`'s visibility as `gone` so that it will hide and you can make it as `visible` whenever you want.

```
imageView.SetVisibility(8);  //Gone
imageView.SetVisibility(0);  //Visible
```